# WPF Animate Grid.VisibilityProperty in code

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, visibility

What animation class would allow me to change the Visibility (not opacity) of a Grid object with a Storyboard instance in code (not XAML)?

So that I can set the to, from, and duration properties before adding it to the storyboard.

Comment: [ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.objectanimationusingkeyframes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code necessary to animate the visibility.

```
    DiscreteObjectKeyFrame dk;

    ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames ok;

    ok = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    dk = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame();

    Storyboard.SetTarget(ok, myGrid);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ok, new PropertyPath(Grid.VisibilityProperty));
    dk.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1);
    dk.Value = Visibility.Hidden;
    ok.KeyFrames.Add(dk);

    sb.Children.Add(ok);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` with some `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`.

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495446/setting-the-visibility-of-an-element-to-collapsed-when-storyboard-completes-usin). The only work to do is translating that to C# code. (Which shouldn't be a huge problem.)