# Blink animation style for period of time

Tags: wpf, storyboard

So i have `StackPanel` that i want to show with blink `Style` for several seconds and after that i want it to disappear.

I do not want it to be Automatically but control it from code behind:

So currently this is what i have so far:

```
<Style x:Key="FaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="FadeStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Opacity)" 
                                     From="0"
                                     To="1" Duration="0:0:0.7"
                                     RepeatBehavior="0:0:5"
                                     AutoReverse="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeStoryboard}"/>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Code behind:

```
StackPanel sp;
Storyboard storyboard = Resources["FaderStyle"] as Storyboard;
            if (storyboard != null)
                storyboard.Begin(sp);
```

So currently my StackPanel `Visibility` is `Collapsed` and after i start the Animation i still cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. But your approach to starting the animation is wrong. The trigger starts the animation when `Visibility` changes to `Visible`. Not the other way around (which your last piece of code indicates) *starting the animation does not change visibility because you didn't write the logic to do that*

So with your given code, you need to change the visibility in order to start the animation:

```
StackPanel sp;
sp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Note that the animation only starts when it enters `Visible` state. Which means you need to make it collapsed or hidden first.

Comment: @falukky Did you try to change visibility instead of starting the storyboard?

Comment: YEs now i see what you talking about, BTW how can i change it back to Collapsed  inside the Storyboard ?

Comment: @falukky using `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495505/366064