# Resizing window with menu

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, side-menu

I've come across a problem with making menus within a re-sizeable window. I've made a test app to demonstrate my problem below:

I'm animating a settings menu that transitions down from the top by changing the grid margin. When the settings menu is pushed above the window by changing the margin, if I resize the window height I can see the hidden menu rather than seeing the main screen (green) extending.

How Can I change it so the main grid (green) extends rather than being able to see the hidden settings menu?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
    <Window x:Class="ResizeTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResizeTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    MinWidth="800"
    MinHeight="450"
    MaxWidth="800"
    MaxHeight="900">

    <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShowRightMenu">
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="gridMenu"
                            From="0, -450, 0, 450"
                            To="0"
                            DecelerationRatio="0.9"
                            Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="HideRightMenu">
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="gridMenu"
                            From="0"
                            To="0, -450, 0, 450"
                            DecelerationRatio="0.9"
                            Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Background="Green">
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="gridMenu" Background="Blue"
              Margin="0, -450, 0, 450"
              Grid.Column="1">

        <TextBlock Text="Well hello there!" Foreground="White" FontSize="60" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>

    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="10" Content="Clicky Me" 
    Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: You should set the `Visibility` of the `Grid` to collapsed or hidden at the end of the animation. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495505/6560579) answer on how you could do ist.

Comment: Also you should not use absolute margins if you want to let the window be resizable

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. If I set Visibility to hidden, when I start the animation, the settings window would not start its animation from the top of the window

Comment: @Ackdari If I don't use absolute margins, how do I animate the settings menu in and out of the window view?

Comment: I did't said that you should set it to `collapsed` at the start, but at the end

Comment: The problem is, the user can resize the height of the window when the menu is 'closed' and see the menu. @Ackdari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you change the `To` and `From` Properties of the `ThicknessAnimation` so that it is up-to-date with the height of the window. And additionaly that at the start of an animation you set the `Visibility` of the menu to `Visible` and at the end to `Collapsed` if the menu should not be visible at the moment.

For this I would suggest that you add a field that holds the *openness* state of the menu

```cs
private bool menuOpen = false;
```

And alter one of the stroyboards to this

```xml
<Storyboard x:Key="MenuStoryboard">
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="gridMenu"
                    DecelerationRatio="0.9"
                    Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

and remove the other.

You should also remove the margin of the `Grid` and add `Collapsed` as a default `Visibility`

```xml
<Grid x:Name="gridMenu" Background="Blue"
      Visibility="Collapsed"
      Grid.Column="1">
    ...
</Grid>
```

And then in the Click-Event-Handler you can adjust the Storyboard to the situation and run the animation.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var storyBoard = this.FindResource("ShowRightMenu") as Storyboard;
    var animation = storyBoard.Children[0] as ThicknessAnimation;
    if (menuOpen)
    {
        animation.To = new Thickness(0, -this.Height, 0, Height);
        animation.From = new Thickness(0);
    }
    else
    {
        animation.From = new Thickness(0, -this.Height, 0, this.Height);
        animation.To = new Thickness(0);
    }
    this.gridMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    storyBoard.Begin();

    void animationCompleated(object sender2, EventArgs e2)
    {
        if (!menuOpen)
        {
            this.gridMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        storyBoard.Completed -= animationCompleated;
    }

    storyBoard.Completed += animationCompleated;


    menuOpen = !menuOpen;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy. I just need to figure out how to set the To and From with the updated windows dimensions